# Joining 2 SQL SELECT result into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I wanted to know if there's a way to join two or more result sets into one.
i have the following two queries
First query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on)) as day_month_year,
  db.country.country ,
  count(concat(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on))) as count ,
  COUNT(DISTINCT db.prod_id.email) AS MAIL
from db.prod_id
left join db.country on db.prod_id.branch_id = db.country.id
where  db.prod_id.created_on > '2020-11-17'  and (db.country.type = 1 or db.country.type = 2)
group by
  concat(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on)),
  db.country.country
order by db.prod_id.created_on
```

The second query:

```
select
  CONCAT(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on)) as day_month_year,
  db.country.country,
  count(CONCAT(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on))) as count_BUY
from db.prod_id
left join db.prod_evaluations on db.prod_id.id = db.prod_evaluations.id
left join db.country on db.prod_id.branch_id = db.country.id
left join (Select prod_properties.prod_id, prod_properties.value From prod_properties Where prod_properties.property_id = 5) as db3 on db3.prod_id = db.prod_id.id
where db.prod_id.created_on > '2020-11-17'
and db3.value  = 'online-buy' and db.prod_id.status_id <> 25
group by
  concat(day(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",month(db.prod_id.created_on),"-",year(db.prod_id.created_on)),
  db.country.country
order by db.prod_id.created_on
```

The first query give  the following result:

```
+------------+---------+-------+------+
|    day     | Country | Count | Mail |
+------------+---------+-------+------+
| 17-11-2020 | IT      |   200 |  100 |
| 17-11-2020 | US      |   250 |  100 |
| 18-11-2020 | IT      |   350 |  300 |
| 18-11-2020 | US      |   200 |  100 |
+------------+---------+-------+------+
```

The second query give:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
|    day     | Country | Count_BUY |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 17-11-2020 | IT      |        50 |
| 17-11-2020 | US      |        70 |
| 18-11-2020 | IT      |       200 |
| 18-11-2020 | US      |        50 |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Now i want to merge these two result in one:

```
+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------+
|    day     | Country | Count | Mail | Count_BUY |
+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------+
| 17-11-2020 | IT      |   200 |  100 |        50 |
| 17-11-2020 | US      |   250 |  100 |        70 |
| 18-11-2020 | IT      |   350 |  300 |       200 |
| 18-11-2020 | US      |   200 |  100 |        50 |
+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------+
```

How can i perform this query?
I'm using  mysql
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Please EDIT your question, post the sample structure and sample data that you HAVE.  Then show what you are trying TO GET.  Also show what SQL you have attempted.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and an appropriate database tag.  Your current queries are also useful.

Comment: You already know the joins you just use that using country column

Comment: Is `created_on` a date or a datetime?

Comment: it's a datetime but i need it in 'DAY' granularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The simple way: You can join queries.

```
select *
from ( <your first query here> ) first_query
join ( <your second query here> ) second_query using (day_month_year, country)
order by day_month_year, country;
```

This is an inner join. You can also outer join of course. MySQL doesn't support *full* outer joins, though. If you want that, you'll have to look up how to emulate a full outer join in MySQL.

### The hard way ;-) Merge the queries.

If I am not mistaken, your two queries can be reduced to

```
select
  date(created_on),
  branch_id as country,
  count(*) as count_products,
  count(distinct p.email) as count_emails
from db.prod_id
where created_on >= date '2020-11-17'
and branch_id  in (select country from db.country where type in (1, 2))
group by date(created_on), branch_id
order by date(created_on), branch_id;
```

and

```
select
  date(created_on),
  branch_id as country,
  count(*) as count_buy
from db.prod_id
where created_on >= date '2020-11-17'
and status_id <> 25
and prod_id in (select prod_id from prod_properties where property_id = 5 and status_id <> 25)
group by date(created_on), branch_id
order by date(created_on), branch_id;
```

The two combined should be

```
select
  date(created_on),
  branch_id as country,
  sum(branch_id in (select country from db.country where type in (1, 2)) as count_products,
  count(distinct case when branch_id  in (select country from db.country where type in (1, 2) then p.email end) as count_emails,
  sum(status_id <> 25 and prod_id in (select prod_id from prod_properties where property_id = 5 and status_id <> 25)) as count_buy
from db.prod_id
where created_on >= date '2020-11-17'
group by date(created_on), branch_id
order by date(created_on), branch_id;
```

You see, the conditions the queries have in common remain in the where clause and the other conditions go inside the aggregation functions.

`sum(boolean)` is short for `sum(case when boolean then 1 else 0 end)`, i.e. this counts the rows where the condition is met in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks its works, i need to check the data if they are correct. And the hard way what does it involves?

Comment: The hard way is to make the two queries one. This can be done with conditional aggregation. I've updated my answer.